# downloading a file in python and cancel

Tags: python, download

I am trying to make a simple function to download file in python
The code is something like

```
def download(url , dest):
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, dest)
```

My issue is that if I want to cancel the download process in the middle of downloading how do I approach???

This function runs in the background of app and is triggered by a button. Now I am trying to trigger it off with another button.

The platform is XBMC.

Comment: I think you have to give us a litte bit more to go on. How are you calling that function, are you using a browser to do this, or are you executing it via shell?

Comment: @limelights How would you run Python code in a browser?

Comment: @unwind well, clearly he is lacking in explaining this problem and so I believe he has the probable chance of being in Django or Flask or Bottle and then calling this function. I was just trying to get the ball rolling on explanation. Also, he might be trolling around in skulpt :P

Comment: You can simply cancel the program itself, by hitting `CTRL+C` on your keyboard; but if you want something more complicated than that you need to provide more details on how you are running the code.

Comment: I am running the app inside xbmc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple class to do the same as your `download` function:

```
import urllib
import threading

class Downloader:

    def __init__(self):
        self.stop_down = False
        self.thread = None

    def download(self, url, destination):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.__down, args=(url, destination))
        self.thread.start()

    def __down(self, url, dest):
        _continue = True
        handler = urllib.urlopen(url)
        self.fp = open(dest, "w")
        while not self.stop_down and _continue:
            data = handler.read(4096)
            self.fp.write(data)
            _continue = data
        handler.close()
        self.fp.close()

    def cancel(self):
        self.stop_down = True
```

So, when someone clicks the "Cancel" button you have to call the `cancel()` method.

Please note that this will not remove the partially downloaded file if you cancel it, but that should not be hard to achieve using `os.unlink()`, for example.

The following example script shows how to use it, starting the download of a ~20Mb file and cancelling it after 5 seconds:

```
import time
if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "http://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v9.2.3/postgresql-9.2.3.tar.gz"
    down = Downloader()
    down.download(url, "file")
    print "Download started..."
    time.sleep(5)
    down.cancel()
    print "Download canceled"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are canceling by pressing CTRL+C, then you can use this built in exception and proceed with what you think the best move should be.

In this case, if I cancel in the middle of a download, I simply want that partial file to be deleted:

```
def download(url , dest):
    try:
        urllib.urlretrieve(url, dest)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if os.path.exists(dest):
            os.remove(dest)
    except Exception, e:
        raise
```